# How to add Multiple markers on javascript google maps?

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Hi I am trying to add Markers on my App but still I can't able to view markers on my map, Here is my Code:

TS:

```
loadMap(){

    var locations = [
      ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
      ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
      ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
      ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
      ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
    ];

    //  alert('hi');
      //  let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(13.08784, 80.27847);
     
       let mapOptions = {
         center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
         zoom: 10,
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
       }
       
       var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: this.map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(Map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));


       this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);
   
     }
    }
```

How can I view Markers on my Google Maps ? any help ?

Comment: You are trying to use `this.map` before you create it. How hard would it be to look at the Javascript console and figure this out?

Comment: I don’t see where you actually add your marker to the map. I would expect a call like marker.setMap(map);

Comment: @MikeOne the code looks correct except for what I mentioned in my previous comment. No need to use `setMap`.

Comment: @MrUpsidown I declared it as Map But still I can't able to get Markers

Comment: @guru, yes you have, but after you are using it. In the marker creation you are using `map: this.map` but you are declaring `this.map = new google.maps.Map(...)` afterwards.

Comment: @MrUpsidown I'm kinda new to this could you please correct where I am wrong please ?

Comment: I just provided the details. Just look at basically *any* code sample in the documentation...

Comment: @MrUpsidown Could you able to create an answer for this, where am I done wrong and you can correct it over there ?

Comment: Move this line `this.map = new google.maps.Map(...)` just after where you declare `let mapOptions = ...`

Comment: @MrUpsidown Yeah I get it right, thanks for your time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See the comments...

```js
function loadMap() {

  var locations = [
    ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
    ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
    ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
    ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
    ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
  ];

  let mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  
  // Moved this line up here
  this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions); // changed the "native element" to a standard DOM element for the sake of this example

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var marker, i;

  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      map: this.map // You are using this.map here so it needs to be created before
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(Map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));
  }
}

loadMap();
```

```css
#map {
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
```